# How to create a pipe to format account numbers?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there an expert in Angular, who can take the time to explain to me how one can create a pipe to format the account number?

The account number always has a mandatory length of 12 digits.

For example => `123456789123`

- The variable retrieved from the webService is of type `number`.
- I would like to get this type of display

```
123-4567891-23
458-4698712-15
etc...
```

I'm still too beginner to figure out how I should create this. Would someone be kind enough to help me create the pipe, so I can understand.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'accountDash'
})
export class AccountDashPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(): any {
    return;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help, I apologize if my message is too light.

Comment: `transform(yourInput:string) {///do the stufff with yourInput} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the number to a string and format it quite easily

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'accountDash'
})
export class AccountDashPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(accountNumber: Number): string {
    return String(accountNumber).replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{7})(\d{2})$/, `$1-$2-$3`)
  }
}
```

All you need to do is then apply it to your template.

```html
<span>{{someAccountNumber|accountDash}}</span>
```

You may or may not want to add some error handling in the pipe to detect if it is attempting to consume an invalid account number.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpa5ce?file=src/app/app.component.html)